# How to get current location or move to current location in Xamarin.Forms.Map

Tags: c#, xamarin, maps, xamarin.forms

Since the Map already shows the user location (with IsShowingUser) I just want to zoom to this location. Is this easily possible or do I need to get the location on every platform, since I don't find any GeoLocation object. Only the GeoCoder...
Is this not a common usecase to zoom to users position?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You will need to call `MoveToRegion` method with the position you are interested in.

You can use [Geolocator Plugin for Xamarin](https://blog.xamarin.com/geolocation-for-ios-android-and-windows-made-easy/) to get the location in PCL project:

```
var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(10000);
map.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(position.Latitude, position. Longitude), 
                                             Distance.FromMiles(1)));
```

Updated: Xamarin Forms now includes by default [Xamarin.Essentials: Geolocation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/geolocation?tabs=android)

Comment: What is `locator`? This is never explained in the article

Comment: @Bassie it's var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;

Comment: Love this control, I'm just having an issue seeing/getting the blue dot to show up on the iphone... Any ideas? I don't care about it, but client wants blue dot to show where the user is...

I can movetoregion just fine and get my location, centers the map to my location, just can't see any blue dot, like in maps...

Comment: @TimMaxey you should set `IsShowingUser` to `true` on your map instance

Comment: Now we can use the Xamarin.Forms Essentials wich contains a Geolocation and other functionalities https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/blob/master/Samples/Samples/ViewModel/GeolocationViewModel.cs

Answer (score 8):

### Center the map on your location:

```
var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(5000);
map.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(position.Latitude, position.Longitude), Distance.FromMiles(1))
```

### Zoom the map on its current position:

```
var zoomLevel = 9; // between 1 and 18
var latlongdegrees = 360 / (Math.Pow(2, zoomLevel));
map.MoveToRegion(new MapSpan (map.VisibleRegion.Center, latlongdegrees, latlongdegrees));
```

Ref: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/maps/

Answer (score 0):

> Is this not a common usecase to zoom to users position?

Yes, it is. For iOS just use the MKMapView `ShowUserLocation` property.

From Apple documentary:

> Setting this property to YES causes the map view to use the Core Location framework to find the current location and try to display it on the map.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKMapView/showsUserLocation

So how can you do it in Xamarin?
You will need a custom renderer which extends Xamarin Forms **MapRenderer**. Get the native map and set the ShowUserLocation property to true.

Here is an example:

```
private void MoveToCurrentPosition()
{
  var nativeMap = Control as MKMapView;
  if (nativeMap == null)
    return;

  nativeMap.ShowsUserLocation = true;
}
```

Also set `nativeMap.SetUserTrackingMode(MKUserTrackingMode.Follow, true);` to automatically follow the user.

This may not work when the map is initialised, since iOS couldn't get the user location yet. So if you need to display the current user location when the map appears, just use an EventHandler for `MKUserLocationEventArgs` and use the `DidUpdateUserLocation` event. You can do it like this:

```
private EventHandler<MKUserLocationEventArgs> _didUpdateUserLocationEventHandler;

// In OnElementChanged:
_didUpdateUserLocationEventHandler = (_, __) =>
{
    MoveToCurrentPosition();
    nativeMap.DidUpdateUserLocation -= _didUpdateUserLocationEventHandler;
};
nativeMap.DidUpdateUserLocation += _didUpdateUserLocationEventHandler;
```

Do not forget to deregister this event. Use it just for a usual initialise behaviour. The user should be free to scroll on the map as he likes.