# How to get current location in Xamarin.Forms.Maps?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I need to get the current location map and need to pin the current coordinates. Users will pin the coordinates. When the users pin the coordinates, the data is stored in the database.

I am using VS 2015 /.Net 4.5 Framework - I have to get this application on cross platform - Android / iOS / Windows.  Samples which I can refer online such as MKMapView aren't supported on .Net 4.5 Framework.

How to get the current location map and how to pin the current coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Refer

[How to get current location or move to current location in Xamarin.Forms.Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36630509/how-to-get-current-location-or-move-to-current-location-in-xamarin-forms-map)

OR

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2422805

Comment: problem is with Xamarin.Forms.Map.. I dont have syntax to get current device location

Comment: there are other dll's available.. " mkmapview get current location " however, MKMapview is not supporting .Net Framework 4.5