# with xamarin forms maps, how can i center the map in the user current location?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, maps, cross-platform

In my xamarin cross platform app I am trying to center the map to the current user location, when the app starts but I can't adapt the example I found I downloaded the geolocator plugin for xamarin but I couldn't make it work.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Plugin.Geolocator;

namespace Map_Test
{

public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {

        Map mapa = new Map();
        mapa.IsShowingUser = true;

        var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
        var position = locator.GetPositionAsync();

        mapa.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(position.Latitude, position.Longitude), Distance.FromMiles(1)));



        var rootPage = new ContentPage();
        rootPage.Content = mapa;

        MainPage = rootPage;

    }

    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        // Handle when your app starts
    }

    protected override void OnSleep()
    {
        // Handle when your app sleeps
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        // Handle when your app resumes
    }
}
}
```

I added a new ContentPage and did this but i don't know how to access position.Latitude and position.Longitude values from the updatePosition method.

```
using Plugin.Geolocator;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;
using Plugin.Geolocator;

namespace Map_Test
{
public class MapTest : ContentPage
{
    Label locationLabel = new Label();
    public MapTest()
    {
        Map mapa = new Map();
        mapa.IsShowingUser = true;
        mapa.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(position.Latitude, position.Longitude),
                                         Distance.FromMiles(1)));

        Content = new StackLayout
        {
            Children = {
                mapa
            }
        };
    }

    public async void updatePosition()
    {
        var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
        var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What example did you use? What does happen?

Comment: 'Task<Position>' does not contain a definition for 'Latitude' and no extension method 'Latitude' accepting a first argument of type 'Task<Position>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

'Task<Position>' does not contain a definition for 'Longitude' and no extension method 'Longitude' accepting a first argument of type 'Task<Position>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: this is the example i used: 

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36630649/7945025

Comment: You're forgetting the `await` keyword. The code should run async, but you can't run async code from your constructor, so it seems you need to do some refactoring and probably reading up on async/await.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it this way:

```
using Plugin.Geolocator;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;

namespace Map_Test
{
public class MapTest : ContentPage
{
    public Map mapa = new Map();

    private async void findMe()
    {           
        var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
        Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.Position position = new Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.Position();

        position = await locator.GetPositionAsync();
        mapa.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(position.Latitude, position.Longitude),
                                        Distance.FromMiles(1)));
    }

    public MapTest()
    {
        mapa.IsShowingUser = true;
        findMe();


        var position = new Position(-38.743146, -72.615408);
        var pin1 = new Pin
        {
            Type = PinType.Generic,

            Position = position,
            Label = "Estacionamiento en Pasaje A",
            Address = "custom detail info"
        };

        mapa.Pins.Add(pin1);

        Content = new StackLayout
        {

            Children = {
                mapa
            }
        };
    }


}
}
```