# Continuous tracking of users location

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, tracking

I have xamarin.forms application for ios,I need to implement a functionality of continuous tracking of users locations,for example consider two users "A" and "B"
now "A" can able to know the location of "B" and "B" Can be able to know the "A's" location at any time,Is there any way to achieve this functionality,please provide any sample or guidelines if it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both devices have long distance than using following idea you can track device location remotely.

Using API implementation, device A and B send a current location to your server through **didUpdateLocation** method after that **from device A get a device B current location** and from **device B get device A current location** so, you can track each device location continuously.

As per your requirement, you have to call this API.

e.g   **call API in some of the time interval is the best way** to tacking device location continuously.

Below link help for background location update service,

[Periodic iOS background location updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042894/periodic-ios-background-location-updates)
[How do I get a background location update every n minutes in my iOS application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347503/how-do-i-get-a-background-location-update-every-n-minutes-in-my-ios-application)

Comment: Thanks for help Ashish,i will try this.

Comment: ,@Ashish,i have created locationsmanager and getting the current latitude and longitude,but dont know how to get "didUpdateLocation" method,can you please help me to sort it out.

Comment: @Sahithi, you have to create location manager object and set its delegate methods and then after implement  - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations or refer link for more details  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152003/how-can-i-get-current-location-from-user-in-ios

Comment: @Sahithi, I don't have an idea for xamarin but still, following URL may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36630509/how-to-get-current-location-or-move-to-current-location-in-xamarin-forms-map