# Free maps with xamarin (commercial use)

Tags: c#, xamarin, openstreetmap

Which map should I use when using a commercial application?
* Currently, we are considering an open street map.

If you use an open street map,Is it easy to use Xamarin.Forms WebView?

The functions that I want to do are displaying the current location (real-time update) and adding points in the map.

https://kita-note.com/leaflet/plugins/geolocation/03_leaflet-locatecontrol/index.html
https://kita-note.com/leaflet/tutorial/leafletdemo5_location.html

Also, do I need to save a map image on my device to view the map offline when the network is unavailable?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly, please be careful when selecting question tags, so you don't (for example) select the C language tag instead of C#. Please [edit] your question to make sure you use the correct tags.

Comment: Maybe you could try to use `Xamarin.Essentials.Geolocation`  to get the current location and refer to  https://stackoverflow.com/a/36630649/10768653